# Scroll on a specific DIV Element to the bottom in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to do a simple Python Selenium automation on a website while the website is blocked by a dialog which needs to scroll down to see all the paragraph so as to pass into the website.[image]

I tried to use the code below to scroll the paragraph, but unsuccessful.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get('https://www.fidelity.com.hk/en/our-funds/mpf')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-action="button68"]'))).click()

time.sleep(1)
ele =driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.content-scrolling-behavior')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
```

**html capture**
[image]

I would appreciate any feedback on how to consistently select an option from the dropdown noted in the code provided. And here is the website I looking at: https://www.fidelity.com.hk/en/our-funds/mpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
ele =driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.content-scrolling-behavior')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", ele)
```

**UPD**
Try this instead:

```
ele =driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.container')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", ele)
```

Comment: I couldn't see that long pop-up on my browser, so I can't be sure about the element locator. But if your locator is correct this will work.

Comment: what is the error? or just doesn't work without errors?

Comment: it doesn't show any error..  I've add "html capture" above, please take a look

Comment: I have updated locator. see if this will work now

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll using ActionChain like this :

also, in that div, there are 27 li tags, so I am doing xpath indexing and then one by one I am moving driver focus to those li.

**Sample code :**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.fidelity.com.hk/en/our-funds/mpf")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-action="button68"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.container")))
list_size = len(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='list']/li"))))
print(list_size)
j = 1
for i in range(list_size):
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//ul[@class='list']/li)[{j}]")))).perform()
    j = j + 1
    time.sleep(1)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='btn-confirm']"))).click()
```

Comment: This method can scroll the paragraph down but can't scroll to the bottom so that clicking the confirm button.